# Fix obstructing working copy, without re-downloading folder SVN

Tags: svn

I checked out a (remote) folder to the wrong location (locally). Then copied the folder to the correct location on my machine in a SVN project.
However, when I try to update the project I get an error saying that the folder in question has been skipped during the update process.

```
Updating '.':
Skipped 'lib' -- An obstructing working copy was found
At revision 7460.
Summary of conflicts:
Skipped paths: 1
```

Is there a way of fixing this, so that the 'lib' folder gets updated correctly when I update the whole project without having to delete the whole folder and do a checkout again? In other words I need to avoid having to re-download the folder as it is very large.

Comment: I think youhave mixed up two working copy in one path. Try to separate it. Having one wc in another wc is forbidden.